# Leading underscore before the name of Python module

Tags: python

I have searched around for this but I did not find any answer. I'm looking at a Python code written by someone else and there is a module say "GUI_Module".
This module contains a class which contains GUI related methods. The module is then imported in the `__main__` Python file which makes use of those methods.

Instead of being imported like this with its actual name:

```
import GUI_Module
```

it is imported like this with a leading underscore:

```
import _GUI_Module
```

Now I know about most meanings of underscores in Python but I have not found anything that explains what a single underscore before the name of a module that we are importing is supposed to do.

Answer (score 15):

In the implementation of the standard library in CPython, the `_` prefix seems to indicate that a module is "private", in the sense that you shouldn't import it directly. Usually, this is because its functionality is imported and exposed by some "public", documented module.

Such a private module *may* be an [accelerator module](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0399/#details) - a fast C implementation that exists alongside a slower pure-Python implementation of the same module (and which the pure-Python version tries to import everything from, so that the faster version is always automatically used if available).

Not all modules implemented in C are accelerator modules, though. In some cases, the `_`-prefixed module written in C is the only implementation available. For instance, CPython doesn't contain a pure-Python implementation of the `ctypes` or `sqlite` modules; these modules respectively depend on importing stuff from the `_ctypes` or `_sqlite3` modules (which are implemented in C) and hence can't be used by a Python interpreter that doesn't support Python's C API.

And not all `_`-prefixed modules are even implemented in C! For example, the [`_pydecimal`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/_pydecimal.py) module is a pure-Python implementation of the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module. The [implementation of `decimal` in CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/decimal.py) tries to import `_decimal` (implemented in C) if it's available, and if not, falls back to importing `_pydecimal`.

The only thing that seems to be universally true of these `_`-prefixed modules is that they're all implementation details of some documented, "public" module that doesn't have a `_`-prefix, and that you're supposed to use *that* module instead of directly importing stuff from the `_`-prefixed one.

Comment: All in the spirit of "we're all consenting adults here"   https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-October/025932.html

Answer (score 2):

In the Python standard library, a leading underscore in a module name may denote an *accelerator module*: a module written in C that provides a more performant implementation of the pure Python version, for example `_csv` and `csv`. Accelerator modules are described in [PEP-399](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0399/#details).

Outside the standard library, the leading underscore conventionally denotes a private module, that is one that should not be used directly.  This could be because the main module contains a package's public API, and the underscore version contains implementation- or platform-dependent code.

Answer (score 0):

It does the same as adding any other character. The module name changes and that results in a different module being imported.

There is also a convention that a name starting with an underscore is internal and should not be used by clients.

Comment: So you are saying that the module's name changes somewhere(like in a script in the project flow) and this is not some python related thing?

Comment: No, the main file changes and imports a different module. `GUI_Module` is a module, `_GUIModule` is another, different module.