# ctypes vs _ctypes - why does the latter exist?

Tags: python, ctypes

I recently learned that Python has not only a module named `ctypes`, which has a [docs page](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html), but also a module named `_ctypes`, which [doesn't](https://docs.python.org/library/_ctypes.html) (but is nonetheless [mentioned a few times in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/search.html?q=_ctypes&check_keywords=yes&area=default)). Some code on the internet, like the snippet in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15012814/1709587), uses this mysterious undocumented `_ctypes` module.

A little experimentation indicates that the two modules have similar but non-identical docstrings and overlapping but non-identical attribute lists:

```
Python 3.7.4 (default, Sep  7 2019, 18:27:02) 
[Clang 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ctypes, _ctypes
>>> print(ctypes.__doc__)
create and manipulate C data types in Python
>>> print(_ctypes.__doc__)
Create and manipulate C compatible data types in Python.
>>> dir(ctypes)
['ARRAY', 'ArgumentError', 'Array', 'BigEndianStructure', 'CDLL', 'CFUNCTYPE', 'DEFAULT_MODE', 'LibraryLoader', 'LittleEndianStructure', 'POINTER', 'PYFUNCTYPE', 'PyDLL', 'RTLD_GLOBAL', 'RTLD_LOCAL', 'SetPointerType', 'Structure', 'Union', '_CFuncPtr', '_FUNCFLAG_CDECL', '_FUNCFLAG_PYTHONAPI', '_FUNCFLAG_USE_ERRNO', '_FUNCFLAG_USE_LASTERROR', '_Pointer', '_SimpleCData', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__', '_c_functype_cache', '_calcsize', '_cast', '_cast_addr', '_check_size', '_ctypes_version', '_dlopen', '_endian', '_memmove_addr', '_memset_addr', '_os', '_pointer_type_cache', '_reset_cache', '_string_at', '_string_at_addr', '_sys', '_wstring_at', '_wstring_at_addr', 'addressof', 'alignment', 'byref', 'c_bool', 'c_buffer', 'c_byte', 'c_char', 'c_char_p', 'c_double', 'c_float', 'c_int', 'c_int16', 'c_int32', 'c_int64', 'c_int8', 'c_long', 'c_longdouble', 'c_longlong', 'c_short', 'c_size_t', 'c_ssize_t', 'c_ubyte', 'c_uint', 'c_uint16', 'c_uint32', 'c_uint64', 'c_uint8', 'c_ulong', 'c_ulonglong', 'c_ushort', 'c_void_p', 'c_voidp', 'c_wchar', 'c_wchar_p', 'cast', 'cdll', 'create_string_buffer', 'create_unicode_buffer', 'get_errno', 'memmove', 'memset', 'pointer', 'py_object', 'pydll', 'pythonapi', 'resize', 'set_errno', 'sizeof', 'string_at', 'wstring_at']
>>> dir(_ctypes)
['ArgumentError', 'Array', 'CFuncPtr', 'FUNCFLAG_CDECL', 'FUNCFLAG_PYTHONAPI', 'FUNCFLAG_USE_ERRNO', 'FUNCFLAG_USE_LASTERROR', 'POINTER', 'PyObj_FromPtr', 'Py_DECREF', 'Py_INCREF', 'RTLD_GLOBAL', 'RTLD_LOCAL', 'Structure', 'Union', '_Pointer', '_SimpleCData', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '__version__', '_cast_addr', '_memmove_addr', '_memset_addr', '_pointer_type_cache', '_string_at_addr', '_unpickle', '_wstring_at_addr', 'addressof', 'alignment', 'buffer_info', 'byref', 'call_cdeclfunction', 'call_function', 'dlclose', 'dlopen', 'dlsym', 'get_errno', 'pointer', 'resize', 'set_errno', 'sizeof']
```

I momentarily thought that perhaps what I was seeing was an ["accelerator module"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0399/), but I think it can't be, because the [current implementation of `ctypes`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.0/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py) *unconditionally* imports stuff from `_ctypes`. Nor is it clear that `_ctypes` is just an implementation detail; it exposes at least one public member, `PyObj_FromPtr`, that is useful, not available via the `ctypes` module, and not used anywhere within the CPython source - perhaps suggesting that it's meant for us to import and use when writing Python code?

How come Python has these two modules with basically the same name? What's the division of responsibilities between the two, and when would I want to use one over the other? Should I regard `_ctypes` as a part of the standard library, or as an implementation detail that I shouldn't be touching?

Comment: I first heard about in [comment](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2007/08/24/python-di/#comment-181095) by "Tiran". The source code for it is in py 3.8 is [`.../Modules/_ctypes/callproc.c `](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.0/Modules/_ctypes/callproc.c). The `_c` prefix on `_ctypes` by convention indicates it's code written in C and an implementation detail of the cpython interpreter. Use at your own risks — although I doubt it going to go away or have its interface changed at this point.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55157525/leading-underscore-before-the-name-of-python-module

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`_ctypes` exists because a very large amount of `ctypes` has to be written in C. `ctypes` and `_ctypes` *both* exist because not all of `ctypes` has to be written in C. `ctypes` contains the parts that were more convenient to write in Python.

The fact that `_ctypes` has things in it with no leading underscore, not exposed by `ctypes`, does not mean that those things are meant to be used by anything. Sometimes programs just have stuff left lying around like that. There might have been an intent to make it public at some point in development.

`_ctypes` is an implementation detail. Use `ctypes`.