# AttributeError: module 'torch._six' has no attribute 'PY3'

Tags: pytorch

```
if torch._six.PY3:
```

AttributeError: module 'torch._six' has no attribute 'PY3'

Answer (score 0):

It's true. `torch._six` has no attribute `PY3`. At least the current version doesn't. It does, however, have an attribute `PY37` ([see current module source code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/_six.py#L32)). Perhaps that's what you meant? Or perhaps you're not using the PyTorch version that you intended? Without more information (e.g. your intended use case, your intended PyTorch version, your actual PyTorch version), I can only make guesses. In the future, please provide as much relevant information as you can.

Either way, I'm very confident this is an XY problem. `torch._six` isn't even a module that's intended to be imported except by other internal modules, hence the naming convention (i.e. prepended with an underscore; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55157525/leading-underscore-before-the-name-of-python-module)). Such private modules are not necessarily expected to be stable or backwards-compatible, so you generally should not rely on them. If you're indeed trying to check the python version, you should not rely on `torch._six`; you should check it yourself. You can even do it the same way `torch._six` does it, if you'd like (see previous link). But that's a separate question.